# lambda funtion returns whole list instead of element

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

I have a problem where i'm trying to print out 1 specific element from a list using the Lambda function.

I have a list i want to filter using Lambda and i want to print out only "Python" from the list:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
```

When executing i get the whole list printed to the console instead!
I cant't see what i do wrong here.

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]

print filter(lambda x: x[2], languages)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: isn't languages[2] sufficient for this matter?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking `filter()` to return all elements whose *3rd letter* exists and is not empty. That's true for all elements, so you get the whole list. Remember that the filter function is applied to each and every element in the filtered list. From the [`filter()` function documentation](

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if function is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if function is `None`.

If you wanted the 3rd element, you should not use filtering, just select that one element:

```
print languages[2]
```

If you wanted to filter on a specific value, alter the `lambda` to return `True` for those values that you want to retrieve from the list. You could ask for all values that start with `P`, for example:

```
print filter(lambda x: x.startswith('P'), languages)
```

Comment: So basically there's like a built in for loop in the filter function?

Comment: @DanielBäck: yes, the `filter()` function has to loop over the input list to filter the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]

print filter(lambda x: x=='Python', languages)
```

Answer (score 0):

And the equivalent without the lambda and filter, - > https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

```
print [lang for lang in languages if lang == 'Python']
```

Comment: list comprehension seems so much faster